# Passing info from one intent to the other

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an app which reads some data from JSON, and I have 2 classes which do this.

Right now both classes display the full list of registered members.
But what I'm trying to achieve is that when a member is clicked I only get to see that member and not the other ones as well.

Here is the code from both classes:

From the listview:

```
public class Listviewer extends ListActivity {
    
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

       
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
      
       
        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://de-saksen.nl/deelnemers.txt");
                
        try{
            
            JSONArray  deelnemers = json.getJSONArray("deelnemers");
            
            for(int i=0;i<deelnemers.length();i++){                     
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = deelnemers.getJSONObject(i);
                
                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Character Naam: " +  e.getString("naamingw2"));
                map.put("sex", "Geslacht: " +  e.getString("geslacht"));
                map.put("rank", "Rang: " +  e.getString("rang"));

                mylist.add(map);            
            }   
               
            
            
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                        new String[] { "name", "sex", "rank"}, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_subtitle2 });
        
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                Intent intent = new Intent(Listviewer.this, Profileviewer.class);   
                startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });

    
    
    }
}
```

And from the profile view:

```
public class Profileviewer extends ListActivity {
    
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
       
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       
        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://de-saksen.nl/deelnemers.txt");
                
        try{
            
            JSONArray  deelnemers = json.getJSONArray("deelnemers");
            
            for(int i=0;i<deelnemers.length();i++){                     
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = deelnemers.getJSONObject(i);
                
                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Naam: " +  e.getString("naamingw2"));
                map.put("sex", "Geslacht: " +  e.getString("geslacht"));
                map.put("rank", "Rang: " +  e.getString("rang"));
                map.put("race", "Ras: " +  e.getString("ras"));
                map.put("profession", "Beroep: " +  e.getString("beroep"));
                map.put("skills", "Hobby's: " +  e.getString("hobbys"));
                map.put("lvl", "Level: " +  e.getString("level"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }   
               
            
            
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.profile, 
                        new String[] { "name", "sex", "rank", "race", "profession", "skills", "lvl" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_subtitle2, R.id.item_subtitle3, R.id.item_subtitle4, R.id.item_subtitle5, R.id.item_subtitle6 });
        
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                Intent intent = new Intent(Profileviewer.this, Listviewer.class);   
                startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });

    
    
    }
}
```

I recon I have to pass a variable to the other class containing what member has been clicked, but how do I achieve this?

Comment: Heard of intentObj.putExtra and serializable or parcelable data?

Comment: Im quite new to this so dont know that much, why does this question get downvoted?

Comment: Because this is very basic question and SO has a lot many question based on this. Also Google could have helped you. But it looks like you haven't used any of them. That might be the reason for the downvotes..

Comment: Well I actually did look this up but could not find how do this, it was not about just passing a variable but also how to get the right user wich was clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the intent:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
        Intent intent = new Intent(Profileviewer.this, Listviewer.class);
        intent.putExtra("Key", value);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
});
```

Then in Listviewer.java:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("Key"); //for example
```

To pass user data, modify like:

```
String [] users = new String[] { "name", "sex", "rank", "race", "profession", "skills", "lvl" };
int[] ids = new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_subtitle2, R.id.item_subtitle3, R.id.item_subtitle4, R.id.item_subtitle5, R.id.item_subtitle6 };

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.profile, 
                users, ids);

setListAdapter(adapter);

final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
        Intent intent = new Intent(Profileviewer.this, Listviewer.class);   
        intent.putExtra("Key", users[position]);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes something like this would work but how does it know what user or id was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to pass int value:

categoryView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(CategoryView.this, "id::" + id,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent menuIntent = new Intent(CategoryView.this,MenuListView.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("categoryId", (int) id); //Your id
                menuIntent.putExtras(b);
                menuIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(menuIntent);
                //finish();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send basic information when create an Intent object using Extras. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html .

If you had to load a lot of information and Extras is not right enough, you just sent a "key" that you will use to take back all info you need.

For example:

ThisClass

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisClass, otherClass);
intent.putExtra("id", "1");
intent.putExtra("model", "model1");
startActivity(inte);
```

OtherClass

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + T_NAME + " WHERE 'id' = " + getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null)
```